# avoid recursion into specifc folder using filemanip

Tags: haskell

I am exploring the [filemanip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip) library to search for markdown files in a path including subfolders

```
import System.FilePath.Find

find always (fileType ==? RegularFile &&? extension ==? ".md") "a/path/"
```

is there any way to specify a folder name or pattern into which it should not recurse

Comment: yes with the first parameter of `find` (you choose `always` here but you can do basically the same as with the file - they are named differently but they are really both [FindClause Bool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html#t:FindClause) - just use `directory` there to get the names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation we can see that [find](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html#g:1) takes as first argument a [RecursionPredicate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html#t:RecursionPredicate) which in turn is [just](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html#t:FindClause) `FindClause Bool`.

Based on this we can see that we have to pass in a custom `RecursionPredicate` to `find` other than `always`.
One example is to ignore `.git` directories:

```
notGit :: FindClause Bool -- or via type alias also a RecursionPredicate
notGit = directory /=? ".git"
```

We then just use our new recursion predicate with `find`:

```
find notGit (fileType ==? RegularFile &&? extension ==? ".md") path
```

Note also the special combinators for [predicates](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip-0.3.6.3/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html#g:10) to e.g. compose a `notSvn` predicate with our `notGit` predicate via `(||?)` to get a predicate that enters neither directories.